# Keep recyclerview data between activities

Tags: android

My app have an activity(1) that loads a TabLayout, in the first tab I have a RecyclerView, and each item has an onclick event that open another activity(2), when I close the activity(2) through onBackPressed() method and go back to the activity(1), the RecyclerView is empty.
There's a way to keep the recyclerview data loaded for that case?

Answer (score 0):

One way you can go about it is by using a Singleton class which will store all the data and when you load activity (1), use the data from the Singleton class. Here is an example:

```
// DataSingleton.java
public class DataSingleton
{
    public static ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
}

// Use example
onBindView(...)
{
    holder.textView.setText(DataSingleton.list.get(position));
}
```

Since it's static, the data will persist throughout the program. Also I think a similar question was asked before but can't find it sorry

Answer (score 0):

Asked years ago but as for now (2019), you can use LiveData to have your data state separated from UI state and make it observable so UI will update automatically.

[LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata)